# mybatis interface mapper - overloaded methods

Tags: mybatis

Can we have overloaded methods in mapper interface? If yes, how does mybatis differentiate the   elements in mapper xml?

Answer (score 2):

Can we have overloaded methods in mapper interface? If you mean to implement Mapper interface --> NO

Mybatis defferentiate the elements in mapper xml by the "id".

For example if we have an addUser method without annotation we can overload it in xml file by specifying id="addUser":

```
public interface UserMapper {
      void addUser( String name);
}
```

xml Mapper :

```
<insert id="addUser" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

No. I am afraid that is not supported and seems it [won't be](https://github.com/mybatis/old-google-code-issues/issues/231). More recent request was [made](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/705) for the same feature, but it is marked as `wontfix`